# Extract last item in node list using xpath last() function

Tags: xml, excel, vba, xpath

Using VBA in Excel 2007, MS XML reference (v6.0) and xpath I'm trying to extract a node list consisting of the last node in a set. The XML looks like this:

```
<Routes>
  <Route id="RT1">
    <PrivateCode>PBAO902:3</PrivateCode>
    <Description>City Centre, Corporation St - Hill Hook, Bishops Way</Description>
    <RouteSectionRef>RS1</RouteSectionRef>
    <RouteSectionRef>RS2</RouteSectionRef>
    <RouteSectionRef>RS3</RouteSectionRef>
    <RouteSectionRef>RS4</RouteSectionRef>
    <RouteSectionRef>RS5</RouteSectionRef>
  </Route>
  <Route id="RT2">
    <PrivateCode>PBAO904:3</PrivateCode>
    <Description>City Centre, Corporation St - Falcon Lodge, Churchill Parade</Description>
    <RouteSectionRef>RS1</RouteSectionRef>
    <RouteSectionRef>RS2</RouteSectionRef>
    <RouteSectionRef>RS6</RouteSectionRef>
    <RouteSectionRef>RS7</RouteSectionRef>
  </Route>
  <Route id="RT3">
    <PrivateCode>PBAO905:3</PrivateCode>
    <Description>City Centre, Corporation St - Roughley, Slade Road</Description>
    <RouteSectionRef>RS1</RouteSectionRef>
    <RouteSectionRef>RS2</RouteSectionRef>
    <RouteSectionRef>RS3</RouteSectionRef>
    <RouteSectionRef>RS4</RouteSectionRef>
    <RouteSectionRef>RS8</RouteSectionRef>
  </Route>
<Routes>
```

I want to extract, as a node list, the first RouteSectionRef in each Route (RS1, RS1, RS1) and, as a separate node list the last RouteSectionRef in each Route (RS5, RS7, RS8). I can extract the first using the following:

```
strPath = "//Routes/Route/RouteSectionRef[0]"
Set dNL = dom.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(strPath)
n = 0
For Each dN In dNL
    n = n + 1
    arrRouteDescriptions(n, 2) = dN.Text
Next dN
```

I am using the following to extract the last:

```
strPath = "//Routes/Route/RouteSectionRef[last()]"
Set dNL = dom.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(strPath)
n = 0
For Each dN In dNL
    n = n + 1
    arrRouteDescriptions(n, 3) = dN.Text
Next dN
```

but receive the following Run-time error:

Unknown method
//Routes/Route/RouteSectionRef[-->last()<--]

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you are using an old version of MSXML where the default selection language is not XPath 1.0. So set

```
dom.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
```

to make sure you enable XPath before doing any `selectNodes` or `selectSingleNode` calls.